# Automatic Colorization - but how to do multiple files?

Tags: command-line, scripts, colors

I have installed everything so [Let There Be Color!](https://github.com/satoshiiizuka/siggraph2016_colorization/blob/master/README.md) works.

This command works well:

```
th colorize.lua (file name).png (colored file name).png
```

BUT...here is my problem, **how do I make a script that can colorize all pictures in one folder?** I scanned a few 8 mm movies and a lot of old photographs so it's impossible to do them all one by one.

I saw someone who used the same plugin on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdYS6MR2yMs). But I can not get the script working:

```
do echo "$file" th colorize.lua "$file" "${file%.jpg}.png"
```

Comment: Have you considered a loop? http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: are the filenames all ending in `.png`?

Comment: I am new at the terminal. How do I write the comando si its right with the loop? I read about the "echo" but I don't know where to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you're missing the definition of your `$file` variable...

Since the usage for your command is to simply specify the input file and a name for the output file, you could use (inside the directory where everything is a file you want to "colorize"):

```
for file in * ; do echo th colorize.lua "$file" "${file/./-color.}" ; done
```

The `echo` is just for testing, to see if the right files are being found and the right thing is going to be done with them. Once you have done it with `echo` and checked that the right files were found and the right names were output, then do it without echo to actually change the files:

```
for file in * ; do th colorize.lua "$file" "${file/./-color.}" ; done
```

But this will match **all the files** in the directory and assumes that they all have a `.` which will be replaced with `-color.` (if there is more than one dot, the first dot will be replaced) for example:

```
old-pic1.png -> old-pic1-color.png
old-pic2.png -> old-pic2-color.png
```

instead of using `*` which matches *all* files, it would be better to glob for the files by part of their name which is in common, like `.png` then you could replace `*` with `*.png` to find only files with that ending.